# Release Management Azure Website

Tags: azure-web-app-service, ms-release-management

How can I publish to an Azure Website (NO VM!) using Microsoft Release Management.

At the moment, ms release management only seems to support deploying to Azure VM's.  I like MS Release Management system as it lets me control my deployment variables across multiple deployment stages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Release Management now offers built-in steps to manage Azure App Services.  In a Release Management process add the **Azure App Service Deploy** step, and configure for your website.  Note that this step requires your site to be published as a .zip file.

In addition to the deploy step, it is best practice to deploy to an inactive slot, or stop / start the site using the **Azure App Service Manage** steps in Release Management.

Comment: Better late than pregnant ;)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, this is not a supported scenario out of the box.

Your best bet here is to use an agent-based release template with a "springboard" server to manage the release, and custom PowerShell scripts that use the Azure SDK to interact with Azure. One of my colleagues did the leg work to figure it out a few months ago, and has a few comprehensive [blog](http://www.incyclesoftware.com/2015/03/continuous-deployment-to-azure-web-sites-with-release-management/) [posts](http://www.incyclesoftware.com/2015/02/continuous-deployments-azure-platform-service-environments/) describing how he accomplished deploying an Azure Web Application via RM.

Comment: So, I have really tried to follow this single blog post and found it less than comprehensive.  So much information is either left out or assumed that i makes it almost impossible to follow.

Answer (score 0):

For now, you should take a look at the new build system, it has an out of box task to deploy a package to azure web app.